# Use the image inserted in SummerNote in Ruby on Rails by linking CarrierWave and Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary, summernote

I am in the process of creating a web app with Ruby on Rails.

I introduce SummerNote to make the article creation form user-friendly.
We have also introduced CarrierWave for user avatars.
I’m using Heroku in production.

However, Heroku is going to erase images after 24h. So I added Cloudinary as an addon for keeping images on Heroku.

But the images inserted in the text field in SummerNote was erased.
I am in trouble because I do not know how to link summer note, carrier wave and Cloudinary.

Does anyone know how to link to SummerNote and carrier wave and Cloudinary?

**My CODE**

summernote-init.coffee

```
sendFile = (file, toSummernote) ->
  data = new FormData
  data.append 'upload[image]', file
  $.ajax
    data: data
    type: 'POST'
    url: '/uploads'
    cache: false
    contentType: false
    processData: false
    success: (data) ->
      img = document.createElement('IMG')
      img.src = data.url
      console.log data
      img.setAttribute('id', "sn-image-#{data.upload_id}")
      toSummernote.summernote 'insertNode', img      

deleteFile = (file_id) ->
  $.ajax
    type: 'DELETE'
    url: "/uploads/#{file_id}"
    cache: false
    contentType: false
    processData: false

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote
      lang: 'ja-JP'
      height: 400
      callbacks:
        onImageUpload: (files) ->
          sendFile files[0], $(this)
        onMediaDelete: (target, editor, editable) ->
          upload_id = target[0].id.split('-').slice(-1)[0]
          console.log upload_id
          if !!upload_id
            deleteFile upload_id
          target.remove()
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  process :convert => 'png' 

end
```

uploaders_controller.rb

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
    @upload.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { url: @upload.image.url, upload_id: @upload.id } }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
    @remember_id = @upload.id
    @upload.destroy
    FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/upload/image/#{@remember_id}")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { status: :ok } }
    end
  end

  private

  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:image)
  end
end
```

**Referred to [site](https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails/blob/master/example/README.md)**

---

**MyError**

terminal

```
Started POST "/uploads" for ::1 at 2020-05-19 13:46:50 +0900
Processing by UploadsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"upload"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fc262966fc8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/1v/z9ljm971349c50_qs5f5wy_h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20200519-19326-wz6m90.jpg>, @original_filename="jiyu.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[image]\"; filename=\"jiyu.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "uploads" ("image", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["image", "dtcgxdmlua3jd5ddxkpg.png"], ["created_at", "2020-05-19 04:46:50.050482"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-19 04:46:50.050482"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "image" = 'image/upload/v1589863584/dtcgxdmlua3jd5ddxkpg.png' WHERE "uploads"."id" = ?  [["id", 7]]
   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 1710ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)


Started GET "/posts/null" for ::1 at 2020-05-19 13:46:51 +0900
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"null"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=null):
```

[my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWOz4.png)

When I check the dashboard of Cloudinary, the image is saved but not displayed.

Can you tell me how to solve it?
Or what do I need to know?

Comment: Looks like the ID coming back to rails is 'null' so it causes the error in your console. What is the output of `console.log upload_id` line you have and what happens if you run a request from the console with /posts/7? Does that work?

Comment: I reseted the database. So the POST ID changed from 7 to 1. It ’s when I found POST ID 1.                  irb(main):002:0> @post = Post.find(1)
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "test", text: "<p>tset<img src=\"null\" id=\"sn-image-1\"></p>", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-05-20 04:17:41", updated_at: "2020-05-20 04:17:41">
irb(main):003:0>    thank you for your help